# Codeigniter Update doesn't work

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

i'm having trouble getting my update to work. delete, view and add work fine.

this is my extraoptie_model:

```
function update($id, $extraOptie) {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('extraOptie', $extraOptie);
}
```

my controller:

```
    function update($id) {
    //  Check admin if not Acces Denied
    $gebruiker = $this->session->userdata('gebruiker');
    if ($gebruiker->accountLevel != "admin") {
        $data['title'] = 'Acces Denied';
        $partials = array('header' => 'main_header', 'content' => 'admin_noacces', 'footer' => 'main_footer');
        $this->template->load('main_master', $partials, $data);
    } else {
        // prefill form values
        $extraOptie = $this->extraoptie_model->get($id);
        $data['id'] = $id;
        $data['beschrijving'] = $extraOptie->beschrijving;
        $data['actuelePrijs'] = $extraOptie->actuelePrijs;
        $data['soort'] = $extraOptie->soort;
        $data['aantalGangen'] = $extraOptie->aantalGangen;
        $data['tabelNaam'] = $extraOptie->tabelNaam;

        // set common properties
        $data['title'] = 'Extra optie update';
        $data['message'] = '';
        $data['action'] = site_url('admin/extraoptie/updateExtraOptie/');

        //  load view
        $partials = array('header' => 'main_header', 'content' => 'admin_extraoptieedit', 'footer' => 'main_footer');
        $this->template->load('main_master', $partials, $data);
    }
}

function updateExtraOptie() {
    //  Check admin if not Acces Denied
    $gebruiker = $this->session->userdata('gebruiker');
    if ($gebruiker->accountLevel != "admin") {
        $data['title'] = 'Acces Denied';
        $partials = array('header' => 'main_header', 'content' => 'admin_noacces', 'footer' => 'main_footer');
        $this->template->load('main_master', $partials, $data);
    } else {
        // set common properties
        $data['title'] = 'Update extra optie';
        $data['action'] = site_url('admin/extraoptie/updateExtraOptie');


        // save data
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $extraOptie = array('beschrijving' => $this->input->post('beschrijving'),
            'actuelePrijs' => $this->input->post('actuelePrijs'),
            'soort' => $this->input->post('soort'),
            'aantalGangen' => $this->input->post('aantalGangen'),
            'tabelNaam' => $this->input->post('tabelNaam'));

        if ($extraOptie['aantalGangen'] == '') {
            $extraOptie['aantalGangen'] = null;
        }
        if ($extraOptie['tabelNaam'] == '') {
            $extraOptie['tabelNaam'] = null;
        }

        $this->extraoptie_model->update($id, $extraOptie);

        // set user message
        $data['message'] = '<div class="success">update success</div>';


        //  redirect to index
        redirect('admin/extraoptie/index', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

my view:

```
<table class='centered text'>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>">
    <?php
    $hidden = array('id' => $id);
    form_hidden($hidden);
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo form_label('Beschrijving:', 'beschrijving'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_textarea(array('name' => 'beschrijving', 'id' => 'beschrijving', 'value' => $beschrijving, 'cols' => '30', 'rows' => '5')); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>   
        <td><?php echo form_label('Prijs:', 'prijs'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'actuelePrijs', 'id' => 'actuelePrijs', 'value' => $actuelePrijs, 'size' => '10')); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo form_label('Soort:', 'soort'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'soort', 'id' => 'soort', 'value' => $soort, 'size' => '30')); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo form_label('Aantal gangen:', 'aantalGangen'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'aantalGangen', 'id' => 'aantalGangen', 'value' => $aantalGangen, 'size' => '10')); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo form_label('Tabel naam:', 'tabelNaam'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'tabelNaam', 'id' => 'tabelNaam', 'value' => $tabelNaam, 'size' => '30')); ?></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2' class='center'>
            <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Opslaan', 'id="opslaan"');; ?>
            <?php echo form_button('annuleer', 'Annuleren', 'id="annuleer"'); ?>
            <?php form_close(); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

All help is welcome have been working on it for couple of hours and can't seem to find the problem.

Grtz Nella

Answer (score 0):

possibly the issue arises from the fact that 
you have a php form_close(); 
but do not have a php form_open(); 
not sure offhand how CI would react to a close without an open.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CSRF protection enabled? If so, you will need to either use form_open(), as steve has said, or add a hidden input with your csrf token such as:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your quick response!

I have found the error after staring at the code for another couple of hours together w/ a friend.

the problem was i didn't echo form_hidden($hidden) so no id was passed through to the update model.

```
<table class='centered text'>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>">
<?php
$hidden = array('id' => $id);
form_hidden($hidden);
?>
<tr>
```

so it had to be:

```
<table class='centered text'>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>">
<?php
$hidden = array('id' => $id);
echo form_hidden($hidden);
?>
<tr>
```